# How to pass a value inside javascript to managed bean property without using hidden tags in JSF?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, portlet

we wonder that if it is possible to get managed bean property value inside the javascript method in facelets or pass a javascript value to managed bean property but without using hidden tags?

When we search about them what we see are all about the examples or solutions that use html hidden tags or hidden button's click events. But this method is not useful for us when we need much data exchange between managedbean and javascript as it needs lots of hidden tags.

Comment: If you have much data to send to a managebean, create a json object, store its text in a hidden field using JSON.stringify and deserialize it on the server. This way you can store as much data as you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a json object with name value pair like in a map and send them as a request parameters. You can have a `p:remoteCommand` which could be called from your javascript function like below

```
function sendParams() {
    passToJSFManagedBean ([ {
                  name : 'sno',
                  value : 1
                 },   
                 {
                   name : 'name',
                   value : srikanth
                 }  
               ]);   
}
```

The above `passToJSFManagedBean` should be a name of a remote command function like below

```
 <p:remoteCommand name="passToJSFManagedBean" id="passToJSFManagedBeancmd"
                action="#{myBean.getParams}"
                process="@this" />
```

You can access the params passed in your managed bean action

```
   public void getParams() {
        String sno= FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()  
           .get("sno");    
 //same way you can get name
   }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Srikanth, thanks for your suggestion. It really work nice. Could you show us how to get bean values in javascript without using hidden tags in xhtml? When we try to alert in javascript we see #{myBean.myParam} is null. Is it possible to use remoteCommand to get values from bean or is there any other ways to get values to use in javascript?

Comment: This is gold! I was always passing javascript values from jquery thru inputHidden but this is a far nicer solution. Thx