# Set managedBean attribute by jQuery function

Tags: jquery, jsf

I am developing a project where I integrate JQuery plugin FullCalendar with a JSF application. I would like to set the calEvent.start value for ManagedBean within the JQuery eventClick function: function (calEvent, jsEvent view). However, the value passed within the jQuery function is received as empty by ManagedBean, since I'm printando the same on the GlassFish log. What happens? Here is the template page code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/default.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/cssLayout.css"/>
        <h:outputScript  name="jquery.min.js" library="js"/> 
        <h:outputScript  name="moment.min.js" library="js"/>
        <h:outputScript  name="fullcalendar.min.js" library="js"/> 
        <h:outputScript  name="lang-all.js" library="js"/> 
        <h:outputScript name="fullcalendar.print.css" library="css"/>
        <h:outputScript name="fullcalendar.css" library="css"/>


        <h:outputStylesheet name="fullcalendar.css" library="css"  /> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myvalue = null;

            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: ''
                    },
                    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
                    selectable: true,
                    selectHelper: true,
                    select: function (start, end) {
                        var title = prompt('Motivo da consulta:');
                        var eventData;
                        if (title) {
                            eventData = {
                                title: title,
                                start: start,
                                end: end
                            };

                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true

                            $('.motivo').val(eventData.title);

                            $('.horaInicio').val(eventData.start);

                            $('.horaTermino').val(eventData.end);
                            $('.dataSelecionada').val(eventData.start.format());


                        }
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                    },
                    lang: 'pt',
                    editable: true,
                    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                    events: #{agendamentoManagedBean.jsonArray}


                    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

                        // alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title +' Data '+calEvent.start);

            #{agendamentoManagedBean.testeClicaEvento(calEvent.start)}
                    }

                });


             });


        </script>
        <script type="text/css">

            .body {
                margin: 40px 10px !important;
                padding: 0 !important;


                //font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif !important;
                font-size: 12px !important;
            }

            #calendar {
                max-width: 900px !important;
                margin: 0 auto !important;
             }

        </script>

        <title>Facelets Template</title>

    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <div id="top">
            <ui:insert name="top">Top</ui:insert>
        </div>

        <div id="content" class="center_content">
            <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
        </div>

        <div id="bottom">
            <ui:insert name="bottom">Bottom</ui:insert>
        </div>

    </h:body>

</html>
```

Below is part of ManagedBean code:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "agendamentoManagedBean")
@SessionScoped
public class AgendamentoManagedBean {



    public void testeClicaEvento(String str) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
        logger.info("*********DATA EVENTO SELECIONADO *****" + str);

    }

}
```

Comment: Check here... duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258740/how-to-pass-a-value-inside-javascript-to-managed-bean-property-w or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696722/how-to-pass-javascript-values-to-jsf-el-and-backing-bean

Comment: Sorry, but, I can pass values from JavaScript to a h:inputText. My problem is that I'm not able to get the values about the FullCalendar event when the line is clicked. The message "*********DATA EVENTO SELECIONADO ***** is rendered, but the "str" variable is always empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call managedbean method using primefaces p:remotecommand.

```
<p:remotecommand name="callBeanMethod" listener=" #{agendamentoManagedBean.testeClicaEvento"/>
```

In eventClick

```
 eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
     callBeanMethod([{name:'startDate',value:calEvent.start}]);
}
```

In Bean

```
public void testeClicaEvento(){
String startDatString = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()
                .get("startDate");
}
```

It is better to use primefaces schedule which will be much more easier to implement with jsf.

Answer (score 0):

Is the function executed when you click the event? I doubt that. The #{...} in the following piece of code (taken from the example above) is 'executed' when the page is first rendered

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

    // alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title +' Data '+calEvent.start);
    #{agendamentoManagedBean.testeClicaEvento(calEvent.start)}
}
```

So then calEvent.start evaluates to 'null' (there is no *EL* variable calEvent) and that is what you see. If you want to execute a method on the server at that moment in time, use an omnifaces [`o:commandScript`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/commandScript).

But isn't it much easier to just use [PrimeFaces schedule](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml) which is all ready to go, instead of reinventing the wheel?