# How to set values to the members of JSF managed bean from xhtml page?

Tags: jsf, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass the values between xhtml pages using the Request Scoped JSF Managed Bean, GendersManager.java in jsf as follows:

**Page Flow:**

index.xhtml ---hyper link---> GendersInsertCreateKeyin.xhtml ---Confirm---> GendersInsertCreateConfirm.xhtml ---Commit---> GendersInsertCreateCommitted.xhtml ---Committed---> index.xhtml

**Issue:**

The *field vaues are shown in "GendersInsertCreateConfirm.xhtml" (ie.during 1st navigation)* but **field values become null/empty string in GendersInsertCreateCommitted.xhtml (ie. during 2nd navigation)** during the page flows.

***Update:***

a) Converting the user interfaces, ***h:outputText*** to **h:inputText** in GendersInsertCreateConfirm.xhtml retains field values during the page flows.

b) After Converting the user interfaces, ***h:outputText*** to **h:inputText** and setting its parameter **readonly=true**, field values become null/empty string during the page flows.

c) tried to set the values to the member variables of jsf managed bean,GendersManager with the following javascript code from GendersInsertCreateConfirm.xhtml:

```
<h:commandButton id="insertCreateConfirmBtnUi" value="Genders Insert Create Confirm" action="#{gendersManager.insertCreateConfirm}"/></td>
<f:verbatim>
<script type="text/js" language="javascript">
var genderSlNoUiText = document.getElementByid("genderSlNoUi").getValue();
</script>
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{gendersManager.genderSlNo}" value=genderSlNoUiText/>
<f:verbatim>
</h:commandButton>
```

, but throws error that value should have quotes

Please guide me in passing values between xhtml pages using the jsf managed bean.

**References:**

**faces-config.xml:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2" 
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

<navigation-rule>
<navigation-case>
<from-action>#{gendersManager.insertCreateKeyin}</from-action>
<from-outcome>Confirm</from-outcome>
<to-view-id>GendersInsertCreateConfirm.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

<navigation-rule>
<from-view-id>GendersInsertCreateConfirm.xhtml</from-view-id>
<navigation-case>
<from-action>#{gendersManager.insertCreateConfirm}</from-action>
<from-outcome>Commit</from-outcome>
<to-view-id>GendersInsertCreateCommitted.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

<navigation-rule>
<from-view-id>GendersInsertCreateCommitted.xhtml</from-view-id>
<navigation-case>
<from-action>#{gendersManager.insertCreateCommitted}</from-action>
<from-outcome>Committed</from-outcome>
<to-view-id>index.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

</faces-config>
```

**JSF Managed Bean:**

**GendersManager.java:**

```
package com.practice.web;

import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class GendersManager {

    private Long genderSlNo;

    public String insertCreateKeyin(){
        Genders genders = new Genders ();
        genders.setGenderSlNo(getGenderSlNo());
        return "Confirm";
    }

    public String insertCreateConfirm(){
        Genders genders = new Genders ();
        genders.setGenderSlNo(getGenderSlNo());
        return "Commit";
    }

    public String insertCreateCommitted(){
        Genders genders = new Genders ();
        genders.setGenderSlNo(getGenderSlNo());
        return "Committed";
    }



    public Long getGenderSlNo() {
        return genderSlNo;
    }

    public void setGenderSlNo(Long genderSlNo) {
        this.genderSlNo = genderSlNo;
    }

}
```

**XHTML Pages:**

**GendersInsertCreateKeyin.xhtml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Genders Insert Create Keyin</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td><h:outputLabel for="genderSlNoUi" id="genderSlNoLbl" value="Gender Sl No"/></td>
                    <td><h:inputText id="genderSlNoUi" value="#{gendersManager.genderSlNo}"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><h:commandButton id="insertCreateKeyinBtnUi" value="Insert Genders" action="#{gendersManager.insertCreateKeyin}"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**GendersInsertCreateConfirm.xhtml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Genders Insert Create Confirm</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td><h:outputLabel for="genderSlNoUi" id="genderSlNoLbl" value="Gender Sl No"/></td>
                    <td><h:outputText id="genderSlNoUi" value="#{gendersManager.genderSlNo}"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><h:commandButton id="insertCreateConfirmBtnUi" value="Genders Insert Create Confirm" action="#{gendersManager.insertCreateConfirm}"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**GendersInsertCreateCommitted.xhtml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Genders Insert Create Committed</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td><h:outputLabel for="genderSlNoUi" id="genderSlNoLbl" value="Gender Sl No"/></td>
                    <td><h:outputText id="genderSlNoUi" value="#{gendersManager.genderSlNo}"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, please read about [mcve] and try to create a really simple one. Remove the the ejb's, entities etc.

Comment: Edited for MVCE compliance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258740/how-to-pass-a-value-inside-javascript-to-managed-bean-property-without-using-hid or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591301/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-as-parameters-to-jsf-action-method could help you!